# I want to change this indicator from version 4 to 5 pinescript

Tags: typescript, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I want to change this indicator from version 4 to 5 this indicator

"Divergence for Many Indicators v4 by LonesomeTheBlue"

Comment: Why is this tagged with `typescript`? Is TS necessary to answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

The Pine Script™ Editor includes a utility to automatically convert v4 scripts to v5. To access it, open a script with //@version=4 in it and select the “Convert to v5” option in the “More” menu identified by three dots at the top-right of the Editor’s pane:
[image]

note. not all scripts can be converted to V5